# Directly Print PDF File using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

```
ProcessStartInfo infoPrintPdf = new ProcessStartInfo();
string printerName = "PRINTER NAME";
infoPrintPdf.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 
     1.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe";
infoPrintPdf.Arguments = string.Format("/t {0} \"{1}\"",
     Server.MapPath("~/PDF/PDF FILENAME"), printerName);

infoPrintPdf.CreateNoWindow = true;
infoPrintPdf.UseShellExecute = false;
infoPrintPdf.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
infoPrintPdf.Verb = "Print";
Process printPdf = new Process();
printPdf.StartInfo = infoPrintPdf;
printPdf.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

if (!printPdf.CloseMainWindow())
    printPdf.Kill(); printPdf.WaitForExit();

printPdf.Close();
```

this code work fine on localhost, but when it is hosted on IIS it does not print. Can anyone please help me in this regard, and solve this problem. Thank you so much

regards

Comment: If you expect this code to print on a client pc then forget it. It will only print on the server. You cannot trigger a print on a client computer. The only way is to serve the pdf for download and let them print it themselves.

Comment: Are your server and client on the same local network, hooked up to the same printers?

Comment: Client and server is on the same machine on same network with IIS installed. When I print through localhost with port number it is printing, but it is not printing through virtual directory.